# Does an ally that has the plant type via Greenbound Summoning benefit from inspire courage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bard, immunities

The [Plant Type](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/SRD:Plant_Type) gives "Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, phantasms, patterns, and morale effects).".

[Inpsire Courage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm#inspireCourage) is a morale effect.

If I summon a creature with Summon Nature's Ally using the [Greenbound Template](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/templates/greenbound.shtml) (which gives it the plant type), does that summoned creature benefit from my inspire courage?

Comment: Related: [Are immunities only working if you want them to?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70850/33707)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bardic music effect [inspire courage](http://dndsrd.net/bard.html#inspire-courage) doesn't offer a saving throw, so a typical creature that possesses the type [plant](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#plant)—even if that creature had its type changed to plant *via* the feat Greenbound Summoning (*Lost Empire of Faerun* 8 and, by the way, a feat that's not without [controversy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25923/8610))—simply can't typically benefit from any morale effects that a bard's inspire courage might provide. (Also see the example omitted from the *SRD* on [Voluntarily Giving Up a Saving Throw](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#voluntarily-giving-up-a-saving-throw) that's on *Player's Handbook* 112.)

Examples of ways to eliminate or mitigate this issue include the feat **Green Ear** (*Complete Adventurer* 110) that allows a bard to employ a bardic music effect so that it affects *only* creatures possessing the type plant and the feat **Music of Growth** (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 57) that, in addition to other effects, allows a bard to use bardic music to buff creatures that possess the type plant in a way that's different from the bardic music effect inspire courage.

Comment: Dragonfire Inspiration is another good choice here, I believe. Also, an allusion to undead minions also not benefiting, since that's a more common issue that plant allies, might be worthwhile.

Comment: @KRyan Honestly, there was a whole thing about the feat Dragonfire Inspiration in my first draft, but I lost confidence in it: "Each ally so inspired loses the *standard* morale bonus on weapon attack rolls and damage rolls [and] deals an extra 1d6 points of fire damage with his weapons for every point of morale bonus that your inspire courage ability would normally add to the attack roll" (*DM* 17-18 and emphasis mine). A *ridiculously strict* DM could rule that the feat's benefit grants a *nonstandard* morale bonus. I thought it better for examples to be what I knew worked everywhere.

Comment: @KRyan Also, I think I value-added sufficiently with the examples of ways to mitigate the issue the asker has. While a reader *could* stumble over this question while in pursuit of ways to inspire courage in his undead minions, I think the (*ahem*) plant-based nature of the question sufficiently limits answers' scopes. However, that makes *two* questions that could be posed (and self-answered?) due to this one having been asked. `:-)`

Comment: Oh yeah, I already upvoted. Was just some ideas; you have plenty-sound reasons to disregard them (and you don't actually need reasons to disregard them anyway).